# Not sure what this method does

Tags: java

I am confused on what the return statement does. Does it perform that method inside the method or does it multiply something?

```
 public int recur(int n)
 {
    if (n <= 10)
        return n*2;
    else
        return recur(recur(n/3));
 }
```

Comment: You should review the basics of _recursion_, which is what this method is using.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Oh that's something I have not learned yet lol. Thank you

Comment: You should get into recursion. https://www.baeldung.com/java-recursion

Comment: it does some rather sloppy implicit type casting and rounding...

Answer (score 0):

There are two return statements because there are two possible outcomes. If `n` is less than or equal to 10, then the method returns `n*2`, but if `n` is greater than 10 it performs the second return statement (which does involve calling itself).

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement will provide a result to the caller. 
If the caller calls itself, a new frame on the stack will be built for this new call. The program exits when the last frame on the stack has returned value.

To trace this, let's assume the initial call is `recur(15)`, and we get `20` from A as below. A, B and C are stack frames used for program execution.

```
A: recur(15) -> recur(recur(15/3)) -> Go to B -> When B has returned -> Go to C -> When C has returned, A will return 20.
A is gone now, and program exits.
```

==============================================

```
B: recur(15/3) i.e. recur(5)
Note that this is the inner recur()
Now, we hit the base case of n <= 10
n * 2 = 5 * 2 = 10 returned to A
B is gone now
```

==============================================

```
C: recur(10)
Now, we again hit the base case of n <= 10
Note that this is the outer recur()
n * 2 = 10 * 2 = 20 returned to A
C is gone now
```

Tail recursion is an optimization that will use the same frame in lieu of separate frames if the recursive call is the last line in the method. But the above logic can be used for understanding recursion in general.

Answer (score 0):

The result of any expression written after 'return' keyword is returned to that statement of code from where it has been called. Recursion means calling self method from it's body. Here we can imagine that the 'recur' method is written as many times as the recur method is called, with different value of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, I did this:

```
for (int i = -10; i < 200; i++) {
    System.out.println("input " + i + ", result: " + Util.recur(i));
}
```

And I got this

```
input -10, result: -20
input -9, result: -18
input -8, result: -16
input -7, result: -14
input -6, result: -12
input -5, result: -10
input -4, result: -8
input -3, result: -6
input -2, result: -4
input -1, result: -2
input 0, result: 0
input 1, result: 2
input 2, result: 4
input 3, result: 6
input 4, result: 8
input 5, result: 10
input 6, result: 12
input 7, result: 14
input 8, result: 16
input 9, result: 18
input 10, result: 20
input 11, result: 12
input 12, result: 16
input 13, result: 16
input 14, result: 16
input 15, result: 20
input 16, result: 20
input 17, result: 20
input 18, result: 16
input 19, result: 16
input 20, result: 16
input 21, result: 16
input 22, result: 16
input 23, result: 16
input 24, result: 20
input 25, result: 20
input 26, result: 20
input 27, result: 16
input 28, result: 16
input 29, result: 16
input 30, result: 16
input 31, result: 16
input 32, result: 16
input 33, result: 16
input 34, result: 16
input 35, result: 16
input 36, result: 20
input 37, result: 20
input 38, result: 20
input 39, result: 20
input 40, result: 20
input 41, result: 20
input 42, result: 20
input 43, result: 20
input 44, result: 20
input 45, result: 16
input 46, result: 16
input 47, result: 16
input 48, result: 16
input 49, result: 16
input 50, result: 16
input 51, result: 16
input 52, result: 16
input 53, result: 16
input 54, result: 20
input 55, result: 20
input 56, result: 20
input 57, result: 20
input 58, result: 20
input 59, result: 20
input 60, result: 20
input 61, result: 20
input 62, result: 20
input 63, result: 20
input 64, result: 20
input 65, result: 20
input 66, result: 20
input 67, result: 20
input 68, result: 20
input 69, result: 20
input 70, result: 20
input 71, result: 20
input 72, result: 16
input 73, result: 16
input 74, result: 16
input 75, result: 16
input 76, result: 16
input 77, result: 16
input 78, result: 16
input 79, result: 16
input 80, result: 16
input 81, result: 20
input 82, result: 20
input 83, result: 20
input 84, result: 20
input 85, result: 20
input 86, result: 20
input 87, result: 20
input 88, result: 20
input 89, result: 20
input 90, result: 20
input 91, result: 20
input 92, result: 20
input 93, result: 20
input 94, result: 20
input 95, result: 20
input 96, result: 20
input 97, result: 20
input 98, result: 20
input 99, result: 20
input 100, result: 20
input 101, result: 20
input 102, result: 20
input 103, result: 20
input 104, result: 20
input 105, result: 20
input 106, result: 20
input 107, result: 20
input 108, result: 16
input 109, result: 16
input 110, result: 16
input 111, result: 16
input 112, result: 16
input 113, result: 16
input 114, result: 16
input 115, result: 16
input 116, result: 16
input 117, result: 16
input 118, result: 16
input 119, result: 16
input 120, result: 16
input 121, result: 16
input 122, result: 16
input 123, result: 16
input 124, result: 16
input 125, result: 16
input 126, result: 16
input 127, result: 16
input 128, result: 16
input 129, result: 16
input 130, result: 16
input 131, result: 16
input 132, result: 16
input 133, result: 16
input 134, result: 16
input 135, result: 20
input 136, result: 20
input 137, result: 20
input 138, result: 20
input 139, result: 20
input 140, result: 20
input 141, result: 20
input 142, result: 20
input 143, result: 20
input 144, result: 20
input 145, result: 20
input 146, result: 20
input 147, result: 20
input 148, result: 20
input 149, result: 20
input 150, result: 20
input 151, result: 20
input 152, result: 20
input 153, result: 20
input 154, result: 20
input 155, result: 20
input 156, result: 20
input 157, result: 20
input 158, result: 20
input 159, result: 20
input 160, result: 20
input 161, result: 20
input 162, result: 16
input 163, result: 16
input 164, result: 16
input 165, result: 16
input 166, result: 16
input 167, result: 16
input 168, result: 16
input 169, result: 16
input 170, result: 16
input 171, result: 16
input 172, result: 16
input 173, result: 16
input 174, result: 16
input 175, result: 16
input 176, result: 16
input 177, result: 16
input 178, result: 16
input 179, result: 16
input 180, result: 16
input 181, result: 16
input 182, result: 16
input 183, result: 16
input 184, result: 16
input 185, result: 16
input 186, result: 16
input 187, result: 16
input 188, result: 16
input 189, result: 16
input 190, result: 16
input 191, result: 16
input 192, result: 16
input 193, result: 16
input 194, result: 16
input 195, result: 16
input 196, result: 16
input 197, result: 16
input 198, result: 16
input 199, result: 16
```

And bases on the data:

1. Negative numbers make it double
2. Inputs 1 to 9 make it also double
3. 10 and above, results to either 16 or 20

I think that is just the pattern and this is function just might be specific to someone's business